# Test Apex Class for Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am a new developer with minimum experience for developing lightning components. 
I have a LEX component to update case values containing the following Apex Class. Can anyone help me to create a test class? I tried various versions, but none of them are going above 75% of code coverage

```
public class caseStatisChangeCtrl {@AuraEnabled 
public static void updateStatus(case obj,String oId){
    system.debug('obj' + obj);
    case cc = obj;
    cc.Id = oId;
    update cc;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, your code is very strange... Why do you want to update the id of the case by a parameter in your aura component?

Nevertheless, it is pretty easy to test your case though.

```
@isTest
public class SampleUnitTest {
    @isTest
    public static void testSample() {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'test acc';
        insert acc;

        Case ca = new Case();
        ca.AccountId = acc.Id;
        insert ca;

        ca.Status = 'New';
        caseStatisChangeCtrl.updateStatus(ca, ca.Id);

        ca = [Select Id, Status From Case Where Id = :ca.Id];
        System.assertEquals('New', ca.Status);
    }
}
```